# how to fade in images using jquery with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm requesting images (30) from an API and rather than loading each one straight into the DOM, I'd like to make use of JQuery's fadeIn() to elegantly fade each image into view. Can't get it to work.

Do I need to use load() (or live())? The code below works to grab the images from the API, whack em in a new div then append that to #wrapper - problem being it dumps them all in whereas I'd like to fade each as mentioned above.

```
success: function(result) {
    for (var i = 0, l = 30; i < l; i++) {
        var media = result.data[i];
        var imageString = //bits for inside the div;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.className = "imageHolder";
        newdiv.innerHTML = imageString;

        $('#wrapper').append(newdiv);
    }
}    
$('img').load(function() {
$('.imageHolder').fadeIn();
});
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't crack it.

EDIT: thought the below might work. No joy. I'm happy to either fade in the div containing the image, or just the image itself, so long as the little suckers fade in... Appreciate the suggestions thus far

```
    success: function(result) {
        for (var i = 0, l = 30; i < l; i++) {
            var media = result.data[i];
            var imageString = '<a href="#" onClick="getBigOne(\'' + media.id + '\')"><img class="inst" src="' + media.images.thumbnail.url + '"></a>';
            $('<div class="imageHolder">')
                .append(imageString)
                .prependTo('#wrapper')
                .load(function () {
                  $(this).fadeIn();
                })
        }
```

Comment: There's no code there that has anything to do with ".fadeIn()" ...

Comment: yup. aware of that. but will add the code that i have that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines (although I'm not sure it will work with how these are displayed in your site):

```
function fadeImagesIn(i) {
    $('#wrapper .imageHolder').eq(i).fadeIn(600,function() {
                                                fadeImagesIn(i+1);
                                            });
}

//ajax here
success: function(result) {
    for (var i = 0, l = 30; i < l; i++) {
        var media = result.data[i];
        var imageString = //bits for inside the div;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.className = "imageHolder";
        newdiv.innerHTML = imageString;

        $('#wrapper').append(newdiv);
    }
    fadeImagesIn(0);
}
```

**Note:** untested

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would fade all the images in one by one with a slight delay:

```
success: function(response)
{
    var imgs = $(response.data.join('')).hide();
    $('<div class="imageHolder">')
       .appendTo('#wrapper')
       .append(imgs)
       .children('img')
       .each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay((i + 1) * 100).fadeIn();
       });
}
```

If you just want the `imageHolder` to fade in try this:

```
success: function(response)
{
    var imgs = $(response.data.join('')).hide();
    $('<div class="imageHolder">')
       .append(imgs)
       .appendTo('#wrapper')
       .fadeIn();
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/hrBzy/1/

Answer (score 0):

specify a display:none in your CSS for imageHolder. No image will appear with the append command. Then use $(".imageHolder").fadeIn() to control the moment of their appearance

Comment: i would have thought that would work - images are still loading, but not fading in